# Pre-amp connection problem

Tags: operational-amplifier, capacitor, grounding, preamp, condenser-microphone

[image: preamp circuit connection confusion]

I am trying to complete the circuit shown above. I am having trouble as the ground connection is not clear to me. Please help me to complete that circuit.

And also tell me how to connect C5 ground connection and what happened if I ignored that capacitor and ground connection or connect to negative port.

Comment: Can you explain why the ground connections are not clear? C5 is a decoupling cap that helps filter the power supply rail. If you omit it you may get more noise in your circuit.

Comment: I have two questions in my mind. Firstly, where connect my batteries negetive terminal and secondly all the ground connection are interconnected or a special one for third phase ground connection.

Answer (score 0):

C5 is the **bypass cap**. You might google this term, there are many good application and lecture notes out there.

Your power supply can not response immediately to any change in the current consumption of the circuit, and therefore there will be a drop in the supply voltage during current transisents, due to the output impedance of your batteries, or due to the delay in the regulation loop of the regulator. A bypass cap is a big charge reserve, which will supply the current your circuit needs until the battery/dc supply will react. Such a cap works well if there is no -- very small -- impedance between the cap and the circuit, so place the cap very close to the supply terminal of your circuit.

Answer (score 0):

The 'ground' connection is the -ve of the 12V battery, not actual ground!

The battery -ve and those 'ground' points may be connected on the PCB negative rail or any other common point like, for example, the chassis.

C5 is a key component and should not be omitted as that would cause the signal to flow through the battery and result in 'motorboating'.